# Detect incomplete subclass of abstract class, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abc

In Python, how can I differentiate between a concrete subclass and a subclass which is still abstract (i.e. not all abstract methods have been implemented)?

Consider the following:

```py
import abc

class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def do_something(self):
        print('I am doing')

class C(A):
    pass

for subclass in A.__subclasses__():
    if is_concrete_class(subclass):
        subclass().do_something()
    else:
        print('subclass is still abstract')
```

What is the implementation of `is_concrete_class`?

I could attempt to instantiate each subclass given by `__subclasses__()` and catch `TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class <class_name> with abstract methods <...>`, but `TypeError` seems too broad of an exception to catch.

I didn't find anything useful in [Python's ABC Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [function for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isabstract) in the `inspect` module: `inspect.isabstract(some_object)` will tell you whether an object is an abstract class.

It returns `True` for an abstract class, and `False` for anything else, including abstract methods, classes that inherit from `abc.ABC` but are still concrete because they don't have abstract methods, and objects that have nothing to do with abstract classes, like `3`.